# LDAP Authentication in GitBlit

Tags: git, github, version-control, ldap, gitblit

I an quite new with handling Git and LDAP. The situation is that we have installed Git on a server, so now we want to authenticate it using LDAP.

I have my userid and password for LDAP but I am not the administrator of LDAP Server, and nor I can get the USERNAME and PASSWORD so how to install LDAP on git server?

I have the URL and Domain only.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to "install" LDAP to your GitBLit server.

You only need to configure GitBLit in order for that server to delegate the authentication to your LDAP (referenced by an LDAP url, meaning which can reference *another* server where LDAP runs).
See the LDAP AUthentication section of the [GitBLit setup page](http://gitblit.com/setup.html).

> When using the LDAP User Service, new user accounts can not be manually created from Gitblit. Gitblit user accounts are automatically created for new users on their first succesful authentication through Gitblit against the LDAP server.
>
> It is also important to note that the LDAP User Service does not retrieve or store user passwords nor does it implement any LDAP-write functionality.
>
> To use the `LdapUserService` set `realm.userService=com.gitblit.LdapUserService` in your `gitblit.properties` file or your `web.xml` file and then configure the `realm.ldap` settings appropriately for your LDAP environment.

See for example "[ldap authentication with gitblit 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11620359/6309)".